# SqlServer 2008 Need suggestion for optimize my query and which filed to index field in table

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-performance

I have this query

```
select count(distinct user1_.Id) as col_0_0_ from [FriendCloseness] friendclos0_ inner join [User] user1_ on friendclos0_.User_id=user1_.Id where dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, friendclos0_.LastUpdate))=@p0 and friendclos0_.IsInvited=1 and user1_.IsDeleted=0 and user1_.Sex=@p1
```

table User join with FriendCloseness 
query with FriendClossness field LastUpdate, IsInvited, 
User field IsDeleted, Sex where

table User structure involving with query

User
**Id,(Primary key)
IsDeleted,
Sex,**

FriendClossness
**Id,(Primary key, will DBMS set index to primary key automatically ?)
LastUpdate (datetimeoffset),
IsInvited,
User_id (foreign key)**

I **wounder which field do I need to index** and I want to remove date function by creating new field "InviteDate" to store only date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT col_0_0_ = COUNT(DISTINCT u.Id)
FROM (
    SELECT u.Id
    FROM dbo.[User] u
    WHERE u.IsDeleted = 0 
        AND u.Sex = @p1
    --GROUP BY u.Id
) u
JOIN (
    SELECT 
          f.[user_id]
        , LastUpdate = DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, f.LastUpdate))
    FROM dbo.[FriendCloseness] f
    WHERE f.IsInvited = 1 
) f ON f.[user_id] = u.Id
WHERE f.LastUpdate = @p0
```

Comment: It works perfectly, Devart but I wonder why you put Group by in the first sub query I remove it and get the same result.

Comment: The grouping should have reduced the count of JOIN's and, theoretically, some increased the performance. I did it roughly, because I didn't know the relations between the tables. In case this solution suits you, I would be glad if you could confirm it.

Comment: Thank you for updating me on this.